# How to change the keyboard layout language in Windows 10 with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

```
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 1)
```

I want to use Python to change my layout language to English. What I have shown above does not work. I have Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! This is what I did:

```
import py_win_keyboard_layout


py_win_keyboard_layout.change_foreground_window_keyboard_layout(0x04090409)
```